# Composer install failed for some packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Today I ran into a fairly interesting problem with laravel and composer. I have a droplet on digital ocean that runs my application for about a year and a half. Today I created a major release and because of that, I had to run composer install. For some reason it failed some of the packages, outputting **Failed** to download. 
I tried to solve the issue with removing the composer.lock file but nothing happened.

Does this issue familiar to someone?

The stack:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Laravel 5.1
- Composer 1.2.0
- PHP 7.0

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Hard to tell without the composer output.

Comment: What exception message say?

Comment: Actually, there is no output, I mean log. The terminal says the current package, for example symfony/http-kernel failed downloading. Then tries 2 more times and asks me if I would like to reinstall.

Comment: Post those lines, and the surrounding lines. There's often a lot of good information in that output.

Comment: Seem like your connection has an something problem ?

Comment: It was an interesting problem. This issue appeared at the droplet and the local environment too but when I was running composer install today it went through without any errors. Yeah, it must be some connection related thing iIguess. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: check if you have have configured proxy correctly